Ошибка при декларации деструктора
Код выдает предупреждение warning: omission of explicit type is nonstandard ("int" assumed)
и ошибку invalid destructor declaration
Я как истинный программист МК не очень понимаю в с++. Мне нужно задать массив с переменным числом ячеек, при этом не используя vector. При инициализации массива в классе выскакивают вышеописанные нюансы. Код частично сворован и как будто бы у других все работает. Можете подсказать, где может быть ошибка?
.hpp файл
     class newscreen {
       private:
         unsigned char m_size;
         unsigned char* arr;
    
       public:
         massive(unsigned char arrvalue){
           m_size = arrvalue;
           arr = new unsigned char [m_size];
         }
    
         void fillArr (unsigned char i, unsigned char datainp){
           arr[i] = datainp;
         }
    
         ~massive(){
           delete[] arr;
         }

         void vph(unsigned char, unsigned char);

       };

.cpp файл
#include "newscreen.hpp"

    void newscreen::vph(unsigned char vp, unsigned char byte_size){
      newscreen.massive *ms = new massive(byte_size);
      ms-> newscreen.fillArr (0, vp); //строчка дублируется, если нужно загнать еще какие-то значения
    }


Имя деструктора, не считая ~, (и имя конструктора тоже!) должно совпадать с именем класса, а у вас newscreen и massive.

я работаю уже в существующем коде и я как понял, тут принято на каждый hpp файл создавать лишь один класс с одноименным названием. Есть ли пути обхода этого? Если например в классе newscreen я создам как одноименный массив, так и миллион других функций void, но с другим названием будет ли это адекватно работать? И в cpp файле я буду обращаться newscreen.newscreen в таком случае?

Извините, но вы что-то совсем невразумительное написали. Посмотрел еще раз в .cpp-файл, увидел newscreen.massive - а у вас ведь нет поля класса с именем massive. И new massive, хотя нет типа massive.

Весь код - в мусорку, открывайте учебник по С++ на главе про классы, и перечитывайте.

Скажите название книги и номер страницы. Функция и член класса - да. Но полем обычно называют переменную-член класса, а не любой его член. Но даже если не учитывать терминологию, функцию надо вызывать, а newscreen.massive - не вызов. (А new massive(byte_size) не работает, потому что ему нужно имя типа, а не функции или чего-то еще.)

"ЯЗЫК С++И ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЕ НА НЁМ", 84 страница. Ну я в целом уже вроде начинаю понимать что к чему, поэтому комментарий и удалил. Базы, как видите, у меня нет, поэтому дается все со скрипом
